# getting newest record per group and all its values

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

```
ID | serial | created_at | data 1..45
1  | 001    | timestamp  |  ....
2  | 002    | timestamp  |  ....
3  | 003    | timestamp  |  ....
4  | 001    | timestamp  |  ....
5  | 002    | timestamp  |  ....
6  | 001    | timestamp  |  ....
7  | 003    | timestamp  |  ....
8  | 004    | timestamp  |  ....
9  | 001    | timestamp  |  ....
```

i expect a result of IDs 9,8,7,5 as i need the latest row of each serial

```
=> "SELECT * FROM `rig_stats` GROUP BY `rig_stats`.`serial` ORDER BY `rig_stats`.`id` DESC"
```

this however gives me the first occurence, order desc by id so the result is `1 2 3 8` and is not what i wanted.

using `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for Linux (x86_64)`

Answer (score 0):

You may join to a subquery which finds the latest row for each serial:

```
SELECT s1.*
FROM serial s1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT serial, MAX(created_at) AS max_created_at
    FROM serial
    GROUP BY serial
) s2
    ON s1.serial = s2.serial AND
       s1.created_at = s2.max_created_at;
```

Comment: It's interesting that SERIAL isn't reserved. I would have guessed that it was.